# Using group by function in hive to get aggregated counts and get zero as count output when the data is not available for a category in input table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have an input table as shown below and am trying to get the aggregated counts:

Bins/buckets are fixed. This example has buckets/bins - 1 to 90, 97,98. Need counts for these buckets/bins.

[image]

I was able to get the counts for all bins whenever data is available in input table. But when data is not available, it doesn't show as zero counts.

Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Example**: "97" value does not appear in year=2015. Hence it should have zero counts in output table.

Code I tried:

select 'ada' as attribute, year,'98' as bin,count(year) 
as bin_count from mrmg_atrib_monit_psi_db.ada_data_types_negative where ada = 98
group by year union all
select 'ada' as attribute, year,'97' as bin,count(year) 
as bin_count from mrmg_atrib_monit_psi_db.ada_data_types_negative where ada = 97
group by year union all
select 'ada' as attribute, year,'1 to 90' as bin,count(year) 
as bin_count from mrmg_atrib_monit_psi_db.ada_data_types_negative where ada BETWEEN 1 and 90 
group by year

Comment: (1) Please show the query that you are using.  (2) What do you mean by "bins are pre-defined"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select 'ada' as attribute, year,'98' as bin,count(year) 
as bin_count from mrmg_atrib_monit_psi_db.ada_data_types_negative where ada = 98
group by year union all
select 'ada' as attribute, year,'97' as bin, SUM(CASE WHEN ada = 97 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
as bin_count from mrmg_atrib_monit_psi_db.ada_data_types_negative where ada = 97
group by year union all
select 'ada' as attribute, year,'1 to 90' as bin,count(year) 
as bin_count from mrmg_atrib_monit_psi_db.ada_data_types_negative where ada BETWEEN 1 and 90 
group by year

Solution: Replacing the where function at the end to Sum(case) in select statement helped to get zero counts too

Answer (score 0):

By "pre-defined" I assume you mean you have a table of bin definitions.  You can then use `cross join` to generate the rows and `left join` to generate the data:

```
select y.year, b.bin, count(i.year) as cnt
from (select distinct year from input) y cross join
     bins b left join
     input i
     on i.year = y.year and i.ada between b.lo and b.hi
group by y.year, b.bin;
```